# Ckfinder blank popup in firefox developer edition (win64)

Tags: firefox, ckfinder, win64, firefox-developer-edition

I'm using the developer edition of Mozilla Firefox (Waterfox win64). When I work in CKEditor and want to browse a server to choose an image the popup opens and I see nothing. Just white window. There are no javascript errors. Screenshot is here: http://clip2net.com/s/3oq3oEf

Any other browser works fine and I see my images.

Any ideas?